# c function to round half down

Tags: c, programming-languages, rounding

I'm searching a function (in C language) which provide round half down. For example:

```
1.5 after round half down = 1
1.49999999 after round half down = 1
1.50000001 after round half down = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @jtniehof's answer.

```
ceil(x - 0.5)
```

This will always round halves *down*.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [round](http://www.codecogs.com/reference/c/math.h/round.php) functions in math library.

Comment: Oh sorry, these are indeed standard in C99.

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic way:

```
int j;
float i = 0.49;
j = (int)(i + 0.5);
```

Two caveats:

1. 0.5 will always round up
2. The float representation in binary is not always what you expect in decimal. 0.5 is representable exactly; 0.3 is not. Shouldn't be a problem in this case but always work keeping in mind for corner-cases.

EDIT: Three caveats...definitely wrong for negative numbers. If you're doing anything at all complicated, definitely do look at the round functions in the math library, since they've handled the corner cases. But if quick-and-dirty is needed on limited input, this saves linking the math library.

Comment: I need round half down only. I used only unsigned numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
double RoundHalfDown(double f)
{
    double int_part;
    double frac_part = modf(f, &int_part);

    if (frac_part <= -0.5) return int_part - 1.0;
    if (frac_part <=  0.5) return int_part      ;
                           return int_part + 1.0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `roundf(float)` or `round(double)`

Comment: Neither of these is a standard library function, AFAIK.

Comment: I tried round but this **size_t x = round(1.5)** gave me 2, not 1!

Comment: @pierre: rounding exact half up is typical convention. (More paranoid would round 1.5 to 2 and 2.5 to 2.) I'm sorry for missing your first example....

Comment: Oh sorry, these are indeed standard in C99.